# Sympy TypeError when using scipy.stats normal cdf

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

Why does Sympy throw a Type error when I use the `scipy.stats.norm`? How can I solve the equation?

```
from sympy import Eq, Symbol, solve, Piecewise
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np

x = Symbol('x')
eqn = Eq((x-0.2)/0.3, norm.cdf((np.log(100/110) + x**2/2)/x))

print(solve(eqn))
```

Output:

```
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

Comment: What makes you think you can mix sympy-expressions and scipy-based functions? There is a reason [this exists](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/statistics.html).

Comment: John, can you tell us what mathematical expression you're trying to evaluate?

Comment: @BillBell The expression is Eq((x-0.2)/0.3, norm.cdf((np.log(100/110) + x**2/2)/x))

Comment: @sascha I see - thanks!

Comment: Thanks for responding but you've got a really good answer already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Symbolic setup

If you are looking for symbolic solutions, use symbolic functions: e.g., SymPy's log not NumPy's log. The normal  CDF is also available from SymPy's stats module as `cdf(Normal("x", 0, 1))`. The correct SymPy setup would be this:

```
from sympy import Eq, Rational, Symbol, log
from sympy.stats import cdf, Normal
eqn = Eq((x-Rational('0.2'))/Rational('0.3'), cdf(Normal("x", 0, 1))(log(Rational(100, 110)) + x**2/2)/x)
```

Notice that I put `Rational('0.2')` where you had 0.2. The distinction between rationals and floats is important for symbolic math. The equation now looks good from the formal point of view:

```
Eq(10*x/3 - 2/3, (erf(sqrt(2)*(x**2/2 - log(11) + log(10))/2)/2 + 1/2)/x)
```

Unfortunately it also looks hopeless: there's no closed form solution for things like that, involving a transcendental function equated to a polynomial. Naturally, `solve(eqn)` will fail. So all of the above does is demonstrate correct use of SymPy, but it doesn't change the fact that there is no symbolic solution.

#### Numeric solution

To solve this numerically, do the opposite: drop the SymPy parts and import `fsolve` from SciPy.

```
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

f = lambda x: (x-0.2)/0.3 - norm.cdf((np.log(100/110) + x**2/2)/x)
print(fsolve(f, 1))   # 1 is a random initial guess
```

The answer is 0.33622392.